# Python Selenium grabbing an element by XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am currently trying to click an X button on the page so it would take me out of the my current page and go back to the home menu. I tried copying it by Xpath but I keep getting an error no such element

```
//*[@id="uniqName_85_2"]/header/div[2]/div/i[6]
```

Here is the HTML

```
<i role="button" aria-label="Close" tabindex="0" class="tableCell
 hi hi-close" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:trowserExit">
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure why the xpath isnt working

Comment: Please provide a link to the web page

Comment: You may need to implement a WaitUntilLoaded function that waits until your element is on the page before trying to click it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()` and following `xpath`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//i[@aria-label='Close' and @role='button]"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```